# Facebook like box not working on mobile browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, mobile-website

I'm writing a simple splash page for a client to hold a like box widget:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=***********&amp;width=238&amp;connections=4&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=200" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:238px; height:200px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The page displays fine, with the like box, but when you click on the like it depresses without prompting the user to logon and does not update facebook.  This behavior seems to be on mobile browsers only.  On desktop browsers (ie8, firefox, safari) it works just fine.

Anyone had this happen, and if so what was their solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the mobile browsers does not support or have poor suppport for iframe.